# Why the extra slashes still coming even after using stripslashes and strip_tags on the string?

Tags: php, string, backslash, strip-tags, stripslashes

I've one string in a variable titled `$message`.

After `echo stripslashes(strip_tags($message));` I got following output.

```
Michael Clarke commented on Darren Lehmann's status update "&#2008;&#240;&#2008;&#304;&#2008;0&#2008;&#674;&#1594;&#65039;"
```

Now after executing the statement `echo json_encode($message);` I got following output :

```
Michael Clarke commented on Darren Lehmann's status update \"ߘðߘİߘ0ߘʢغ️\"
```

My concern is I won't want the extra backslash and also the garbage data appeared in the final output. How to remove them?

Please guide me where I'm making a mistake in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These "extra slashes" are important so you have valid JSON. Strings are in double quotes and so double quotes in strings need to be escaped. `"key": "some\"value"` is valid, `"key": "some"value"` is not.

Comment: Please, can you edit the question with the exact output? I highly doubt that json_encode will not return a JSON-encoded string.